# C# WPF | How Do I Pass Variables Between Classes

Tags: c#, wpf

I know that many others questions have been already treated on this subject but i didn't find a proper answer for my case !

I have two classes, "MainWindow" (whiches is the main class) and "Informations" (whiches is a WPF control class). I want to pass the variables "FirstName" and "LastName" from "MainWindow" to the variables "FirstName" and "LastName" of "Informations" in order to reuse them later.

I tried this code, but the values of "FirstName" and "LastName" in "Informations" are null. How can i get it to work ?

**MainWindow Class Code :**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        #region Set Variables
        public string FirstName = "John";
        public string LastName = "Smith";
        #endregion

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PassVariable();
        }
        private void PassVariable()
        {
            Informations informations = new Informations();
            informations.FirstName = FirstName;
            informations.LastName = LastName;

            WrapPanel.Children.Add(informations); // Add Label In WrapPanel But It Return Null
        }
    }
}
```

**Informations Class Code :**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Test
{
    class Informations : Label
    {
        #region Set Variables
        public string FirstName { get { return FirstName; } set { FirstName = value; } }
        public string LastName { get { return LastName; } set { LastName = value; } }
        #endregion

        public Informations()
        {
            Foreground = Brushes.White;
            FontSize = 14;
            Content = FirstName + "\n" + LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Informations` class will go into infinite recursion any time someone tries to use either `FirstName` or `LastName`.

Comment: Sorry i don't know what infinite recursion is, i'm a beginner can you explain a bit more please ?

Comment: Even wikipedia can help you with that. Recursion is when a function calls itself, directly or indirectly. It is infinite when the program will not terminate under some conditions.

Comment: Turn `public string LastName { get { return LastName; } set { LastName = value; } }` into `public string LastName { get; set; }` in order to fix the infinite recursion.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Do you think you could help me with the variables problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure `Content` is being updated as soon as `FirstName` or `LastName` change.

You can do that by updating the `Content` in the setters of `FirstName` and `LastName`. There's just one problem. If you override a property setter, you're also forced to manage the property value yourself. This is done with a so-called *backing field*:

```cs
private string firstName;
public string FirstName {
    get => firstName;
    set {
        firstName = value;
        Content = $"{firstName}\n{lastName}";
    }
}

// implement the same for `LastName`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using FirstName and LastName in the constructor, which is before they have been set by PassVariable(). As a result the Content field will just contain a newline character. Personally, I would pass the two values into the Informations constructor.

Comment: Yeah I know it would make more sense to directly add the variables in Informations, but I need the values to be set in the MainWindow. It's for another project where data are get in Main Window and send to a class ! But I'm sorry i'm a beginner can you give me an exemple ?